# Setting a navigation bar selected menu item id from page title with jQuery

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/EAN5K/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Education</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var title = document.title;
    console.log(title);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigationBar" style="">
        <div id="sheight" style="">
            <div style="height: 13px;"></div>
            <div class="menuItem" style="">
                <div  class="tIcon" style="">
                    <img src="images/iconeducation.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="menuText"   style="">Education</div>
            </div>
            <div class="menuItem" style="">
                <div  class="tIcon" style="">
                    <img src="images/iconfastcash.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="menuText"   style="">Fast Cash</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am looking for a way to set the id of the parent .menuitem if .menutext value is equal to the title of the page. At the top there is a link to jsFiddle.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do it:

```
$("div.menuText").filter(function(i,el){
   return $.trim($(this).text()) === title;
}).parent()
.prop("id","someIdValue");
```

That is, filter all the `.menuText` divs to find the one with the matching text, then get its parent, then set the id.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eqapih/1/edit

(I'm curious why you want to "set the id" though. If you want to highlight the menu that applies to the current page it would make more sense to add a "current" class to it.)

Comment: I like it. Thank you for posting.

Comment: I guess it would be better to use a selected class. I haven't gotten that far with the code yet.